# Adding shipping to Paypal PHP SDK custom cart

Tags: php, paypal

Hey guys I have a custom cart I created to pass information over to Paypal and complete the purchase. It's all working fine but now they want to sell items that are shipped. The shipping will be on flat fee per item but I was wondering if there was a way to pass shipping over specifically or do I just add it as another item into the cart?
Here's the code I'm using to add the items to an array called items

```
foreach($_SESSION['cart']['items'] as $item)
    {
        $item = array('name'=> $item['description'], 'quantity'=> $item_qty, 'price'=> $item['price'], 'sku'=> $item['category_id']."-".$item['target_id'], 'currency'=>PP_CURRENCY);
        array_push($items, $item);
    }
```

Then I call

```
try{ // try a payment request
        //if payment method is paypal
        $result = create_paypal_payment($total_amount, PP_CURRENCY, '', $items, RETURN_URL, CANCEL_URL);

        //if payment method was PayPal, we need to redirect user to PayPal approval URL
        if($result->state == "created" && $result->payer->payment_method == "paypal"){
            $_SESSION["payment_id"] = $result->id; //set payment id for later use, we need this to execute payment
            header("location: ". $result->links[1]->href); //after success redirect user to approval URL 
            exit();
        }
```

It works fine but how do I add shipping using this method?

I've tried searching on Google for awhile but I'm not coming up with any valuable information. I also tried adding into the item array 'shipping' and 'shipping_price' but that just returns a 404 error from Paypal.

Comment: setpaymentoptions API, no?

Comment: @ambe5960 Thanks for the response. I came across that but have no idea how to implement it into my solution. Do you have any examples I can look at?

Comment: Have you seen the following link with values used for shipping? https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/